# Using LambdaClient.invoke in QuarkusTest how do I provide custom headers?

Tags: java, testing, junit, quarkus

I'm trying to integrate Datadog into a Quarkus lambda function. The unit test is failing with a `NullPointerException` because Datadog can't get the function ARN from the context. It looks like there is a need to supply this header `Lambda-Runtime-Invoked-Function-Arn` in the HTTP request.

Is there anyway to customize the request headers using QuarkusTest? We are using `LambdaClient.invoke`.

Comment: What I'm doing now is adding a check before creating the DDLambda instance. If the context does not contain the function ARN, then do not wire in the DD lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Generally tests should be as close to the production run as possible, so altering headers does not seem to be the right path.

Is the unit test focused on the datadog part of the code?

**If not:**

If datadog just broke the existing unit tests, you have multiple options to fix it:

With @QuarkusTest you could just Mock the datadog related parts and register that instead of the original [using @InjectMock](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#further-simplification-with-injectmock).

I also found that using @QuarkusTest for unit testing can be a bit tricky in some cases and using plain Junit5 with Mockito can be a bit simpler with less unpredictable 'magic'.

**If yes:**

Since most things involving datadog is about sending data to an external service this might be more suitable for the scope of an integration test instead of a unit test. In that case you would need a test environment, or maybe reconsider if you really need to test external data collection at all.

Comment: Problem is that quarkus test is just using nulls, so I want to make this more realistic.

Comment: That makes sense, but then again, is artificially adding a header more realistic than mocking it altogether? Does it add value to your tests, and does it make the code more secure from regression bugs in the future? That said, could you include the test class, especially the parts where you inject components and where you receive the  nulls.